# How do i upload a edited canvas to cloudinary (or another image hosting service) using vue.js and fabric.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html5-canvas, fabricjs

On my website the user can draw on an uploaded photo and i want to add the ability for them to be able to press a button and it be uploaded to my cloudinary storage. the website is built using vue.js and uses fabric.js for the canvas drawing.

When i try `console.log(canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png'}))`

i get this error

`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.`

i used this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqnJwh6E9ak to get the original image uploaded but now i dont know what to as i believe there is no "file" like that for a edited canvas

Here is how i upload the original file that the user wants to edit to cloudinary (i removed my name)

```
   this.$Progress.start();
   const data = new FormData();
   data.append("file", file);
   data.append("upload_preset", "");
   console.log(file)
   const res = await fetch(
     "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1//image/upload",
     {
       method: "POST",
       body: data
     }
   );
   const uploadedFile = await res.json();
```

so is there a  way to turn a canvas into a file that can be uploaded to cloudinary or is there another way i can do it

Comment: [github link](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/1386#issuecomment-45996957)

Comment: the comment below states thaat "For anyone who lands here from a web search in the future, note that if you're just trying out Fabric.js by loading a local file into the browser, the CORS change doesn't fix anything. The issue is that Chrome, at least, just doesn't like you reading from a canvas created from an image loaded from the local file system. You can create image objects just fine, but if you try to do something like cloneAsImage(), it will trigger the error above. If you use a local web server to serve the file, it should work fine." so i dont think that will work

Comment: You need to set `crossOrigin` to image object

Comment: @Durge i have it like ```  fabric.Image.fromURL(uploadedFile.secure_url, function(myImg) {
       var img1 = myImg.set({ left: 0, top: 0 ,width:500,height:500});
       canvas.add(img1);
       crossOrigin = 'Anonymous'
      });
``` and it doesnt work. is this incorrect?

Comment: `fabric.Image.fromURL(uploadedFile.secure_url, function(myImg) {
  var img1 = myImg.set({
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    width: 500,
    height: 500
  });
  canvas.add(img1);  
},{crossOrigin : 'anonymous'});`

Comment: @Durga This worked. BIG BIG THANK YOU <3 IVE BEEN stuck on this for 10 hours <3